# logrotate is not rotating the log files daily

Tags: logging, rsyslog, logrotate

I have created a logrotate file in the "/etc/logrotate.d/" directory. It is as follows:

```
/opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/*.log /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/catalina.out {
    daily
    copytruncate
    missingok
    ifempty
    rotate 30
    maxage 30
    compress
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y%m%d-%s
}
```

The "/etc/logrotate.conf" file is:

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp and btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0600 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

I have exectued the following command:

```
sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

The "/var/lib/logrotate.status" file is as follows:

```
logrotate state -- version 2
...
"/opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/localhost_access.log" 2018-4-30
"/opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/stacktrace.log" 2018-4-30
"/opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/catalina.out" 2018-4-30
...
```

I added the ... for brevity. there are several more entries in the logrotate.status file.

The following is the output after executing "logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.conf".

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.conf
including /etc/logrotate.d

...

reading config file tomcat-instance_2
reading config info for /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/*.log /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/catalina.out 
rotating pattern: /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/*.log /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/catalina.out  after 1 days (30 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/localhost_access.log
    log needs rotating
considering log /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/stacktrace.log
    log needs rotating
considering log /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/catalina.out
    log needs rotating
rotating log /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/localhost_access.log, log->rotateCount is 30
Converted ' -%Y%m%d-%s' -> '-%Y%m%d-%s'
dateext suffix '-20180502-1525266808'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
copying /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/localhost_access.log to /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/localhost_access.log-20180502-1525266808
truncating /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/localhost_access.log
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
rotating log /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/stacktrace.log, log->rotateCount is 30
Converted ' -%Y%m%d-%s' -> '-%Y%m%d-%s'
dateext suffix '-20180502-1525266808'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
copying /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/stacktrace.log to /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/stacktrace.log-20180502-1525266808
truncating /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/stacktrace.log
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
rotating log /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/catalina.out, log->rotateCount is 30
Converted ' -%Y%m%d-%s' -> '-%Y%m%d-%s'
dateext suffix '-20180502-1525266808'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
copying /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/catalina.out to /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/catalina.out-20180502-1525266808
truncating /opt/appliedpathways/tomcat/instance_2/logs/catalina.out
compressing log with: /bin/gzip

...
```

logrotate can obviously determine that the log files need to be rotated, but, the log files are not being rotated.

the "/etc/cron.daily/" directory looks like this.

```
total 44
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4983 Dec  7  2016 0yum.cron
-rwx------. 1 root root  118 May  4  2017 cups
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root mail  232 Aug 18  2017 exim-tidydb
-rwx------. 1 root root  180 Jul  9  2003 logrotate
-rwx------. 1 root root  927 Nov  8  2016 makewhatis.cron
-rwx------. 1 root root  189 Jan 26  2015 mlocate.cron
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2126 Jul 19  2013 prelink
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  563 Oct 21  2013 readahead.cron
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   55 Jan 20  2016 redhat-access-insights -> /etc/redhat-access-insights/redhat-access-insights.cron
-rwx------. 1 root root  256 Feb 10  2017 rhsmd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  433 Nov  6  2015 tmpwatch
```

I am assuming that logrotate is being called each night based on the above.

Any help in determining why the daily rotating of the logs is not occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe I may have found the problem. There was a log record stating "SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/logrotate from open access on the file /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat-instance_2". It turns out the label was set to "user_tmp_t". After running "restorecon -v /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat-instance_2", the label is now "etc_t". Hopefully it rotates the logs as it should tonight.

Comment: SELinux was the issue. It is running as it should now.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "weekly" by "daily" in /etc/logrotate.conf